# Реализация CSS анимации средствами LESS

Tags: препроцессор, less, css, sublime-text

Всем доброго времени суток.
Начал использовать LESS препроцессор CSS кода. Работа в **Sublime Text 3** и плагином **less-build**. Пробую скомпилировать такой код:

.mixi-frames{
    from {width: 254px;}
    to {width: 512px;}
}

```
@-webkit-keyframes some-animation {.mixi-frames;}
@-moz-keyframes some-animation {.mixi-frames;}
@-ms-keyframes some-animation {.mixi-frames;}
@-o-keyframes some-animation {.mixi-frames;}
@keyframes some-animation {.mixi-frames;}
```

Выбивает ошибки типа

```
Expected start, finish, % or '}' but got m on line 6 in file 'D:\less\text.less':
  [5]: 
  [6]: @-webkit-keyframes some-animation {.mixi-frames;}
       -----------------------------------^
  [7]: @-moz-keyframes some-animation {.mixi-frames;}
[Done - Failed]
```

Собственно, что я делаю не так?) Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 1):

```
.mixi-frames() {
    from {width: 254px;}
    to {width: 512px;}
}
```

Comment: Этот вариант я тоже нагугливал, абсолютно ничего не меняет - та же ошибка. Много вариантов перепробовал, работает только при прямой подстановке:
@keyframes some-animation {from{...} to {...}}
Простите за неформатированный код, не разобрался с форматированием в комментах